# Android - Getting IP of a WiFi-router

Tags: android, ip, wifi

I used function which got IP address like below:

```
public static final String IPV4_REGEX = "\\A(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}\\z";
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()&&(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString().matches(IPV4_REGEX))) {
                    return /*inetAddress.getHostName()+"~|~"+*/inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I noticed it gets first `appropriate` IP address. It works fine till I insert SIM card. After that it gets mobile's IP, not local WiFi! So I'd like to know how to exclude this situation? I want to get only local IP of WiFi-router. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress();
System.out.println("WiFi address is " + android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddress));
```

and add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: this is only return wifi IP address

Comment: I don't know its excludes IPv6 or not.

Comment: Ok, thank you... I'll try and if you are right I'll check your answer.

Comment: It excludes IPv6, but if you set your device in `portable hotspot point` mode it returns `0.0.0.0`.